# How to make table headers non scrollable bootstrap vue

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am new to bootstrap vue .I have used bootstrap-vue 1.4 for my whole application used b-table for my table but the table headers also move when scrolled i want to make them sticky or non scrollable i found that with the new bootstrap-vue 2.0 there is an option sticky-header but i cannot use that because i might break my application is there any way to make the headers sticky using bootstrap-vue 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .table.b-table>thead>tr>th {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

This thing worked for me use it in the app.vue it should fix all the b-tables

Comment: This will definitely work, but with the caveat that it will override any color variants used on the header/header cells. Just remember to wrap the table in a vertically scrollable div

Comment: sticky header attribute on my BootstrapVue project not work. But with this, it runs like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sticky headers are a "sticky" situation. Only `<td>` and `<th>` elements can be made "sticky" (via css `position: sticky`). The table itself needs to be wrapped in a fixed height vertically scrollable `<div>`.

Note that Bootstrap V4.x CSS does not have table cells inherit their parent's background color (See [this issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29244) at Bootstrap's repo).  So you will find that the background colors (including default of solid white) and borders will scroll with the body (the header cells will remain transparent), making the result not overly great.  You would need to make sure each header cell (`<th>`) has a solid background color.

BootstrapVue 2.0.0.rc-28 had to add in quite a bit of SCSS/CSS and conditional JavaScript behaviour to handle this issue.

Comment: I have tried upgrading my Bootstrap to 4.3.1 and bootstrap-vue to 2.0.0-rc.28 the sticky table header works fine here but it is breaking the whole application as some classes are changed .
so i cant really upgrade to bootstrap-vue 2.0.0-rc.28 because it needs much time to find and fix each and every flow

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the fixed height?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try css sticky?

Add class to your `b-table` component and use this class to add:

```css
.myclass {
    position: sticky;
}
```

Or to select table header, here is complete example:

```css
.myclass > thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px; // try more if you have page header/navbar
    display: inherit; // try this and width below to be sure thead response to sticky behavior.
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `.myclass table > theader`?

Comment: Syntax error? I would say using this selector. Not copy/past as it-self. I'll update my response...

Comment: `<thead>` elements (nor `<tr>`) can't be made sticky (easily).  Only `<td>` and `<th>` elements can easily be made sticky (via `position: sticky`), without needing to change the display type of the elements (which changes their semantic meaning for screen reader users)

Answer (score -1):

Sticky headers are now implemented: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#sticky-headers